# Unable to pass an ID variable to a CFC that displays the correct record in a Modal Box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I am trying to display a form that should populate based on the ID from an edit button.  So the procedure I am taking does the following:

1. Select edit button with ID
2. Bootstrap Modal box display
3. Show form within the box
4. Show record based on ID selection

After trying to do this in many ways including creating a button with a form tag and a hidden input, I am unable to display the correct record in the modal Box.  Currently, it displays the first record, but it does not display the record I am looking for with the edit button.  Code below.  Thanks in advance if someone can help me figure this out.

```
<cffunction name="GetOrganizationByID" access="public" returntype="query" output="false" hint="gets one organization by its ID.">
    <cfargument name="OrgID" type="any" required="true" default="">
        <cfset var Org = "" />
        <cftry>
            <cfquery datasource = "#application.dsn.name#" name="Org">
                        SELECT  org.nID,
                                org.nSuperOrg,
                                org.nOrgRefID,
                                org.cOrgRefID,
                                org.nActive,
                                org.cName AS cOrgName,
                                orginfo.cPhone,
                                orginfo.cPhoneExt,
                                orginfo.cFax,
                                org.nAvailable,
                                orginfo.cAddress1,
                                orginfo.cAddress2,
                                orginfo.cCity,
                                orginfo.cState,
                                orginfo.cZip,
                                orginfo.cCountry,
                                orginfo.cWebSite
                    from    Organizations org
                            left join Organization_Info orginfo
                                on org.nID = orginfo.nOrganizationID
                    where   org.nID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#Arguments.orgID#">
            </cfquery>
            <cfreturn local.Org>
            <cfcatch>
```

Button:

```
<td><a href="##" role="button" data-id="#AllOrgs.nid#" id="loadID" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="##edit-org">Edit</a>
```

JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadID").click(function(e) {
        var id=$(this).data('id');
        e.preventDefault();
        var recordata = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); //trim '?' char
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/pathtoCFC/Organizations.cfc?method=GetOrganizationByID",
            data: recordata,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(message) {
                $("#content").html(message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Modal Box:

```
<div id="edit-org" class="modal container hide fade" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                ×
            </button>
            <h3>
                Edit Organization Info
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <section id="my-account-security-form" class="page container">
                <form id="EditOrgForm" class="form-horizontal" action="#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#?app=edit&view=newOrganization" method="post">
                    <!--- <div class="container">
                        <div class="alert alert-block alert-info">
                            <p>
                                Enter updated security information for your account as desired. Fields marked with an asterisk are required.
                            </p>
                        </div> --->
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span7">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <!--- <legend>
                                        Add User Info
                                    </legend> --->
                                    <br>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Organization Name
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="orgname" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cOrgName#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Address
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input id="new-pass-verify-control" name="address" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cAddress1#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Address 2
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="address2" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cAddress2#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            City
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="city" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cCity#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="challengeQuestion" class="control-label">
                                            State
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select id="challenge_question_control" name="state" class="btn-sm">
                                                <option value="#iif(Allstates.RecordCount,DE('#Allstates.stateid#'),de(''))#"
                                                    <cfif isDefined('Allstates.stateid')>
                                                        selected="true"
                                                    </cfif>
                                                    >#iif(Allstates.RecordCount,DE('#Allstates.StateName#'),de('---Select State---'))#</option>
                                                <cfloop query="Allstates">
                                                <option value="#stateID#">
                                                    #StateName#
                                                </option>
                                                </cfloop>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                            <div id="acct-verify-row" class="span9">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Zip Code
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="zipcode" class="input-small" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cZip#" maxlength="5" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label for="challengeQuestion" class="control-label">
                                            Country
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <select id="challenge_question_control" name="Country" class="btn-sm">
                                                <option value="#iif(AllCountries.RecordCount,DE('#AllCountries.countryid#'),de(''))#"
                                                    <cfif isDefined('AllCountries.countryid')>
                                                        selected="true"
                                                    </cfif>
                                                    >#iif(AllCountries.RecordCount,DE('#AllCountries.CountryName#'),de('---Select Country---'))#</option>
                                                <cfloop query="AllCountries">
                                                    <option value="#CountryCode#">#CountryName#</option>
                                                </cfloop>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Fax
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="fax" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cFax#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Website (URL)
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="webUrl" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cWebsite#" maxlength="150" autocomplete="false" placeholder="http://www.yoursite.com">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            Phone Number
                                            <span class="required">
                                                *
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="phone" class="span4" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cPhone#" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group ">
                                        <label class="control-label">
                                            EXT
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input  name="phoneext" class="input-small" type="text" value="#AllOrgs.cPhoneExt#" maxlength="8" autocomplete="false">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <footer id="submit-actions" class="form-actions">
                            <button id="submit-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="action"  value="CONFIRM">
                                Save
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn" value="CANCEL">
                                Cancel
                            </button>
                        </footer>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--- <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">
                Close
            </button> --->
            <!--- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                Save changes
                </button> --->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your JavaScript `recordata` variable contain before the ajax call? It looks like you are setting an `id` variable here `var id=$(this).data('id');` but where are you passing it to your cfc?

Comment: Yes I am supposed to pass it to the CFC, however I may be doing this wrong.  Fairly new to Jquery to be honest.  So when I pass the ID to the GetOrganizationByID Method, the query should only send back that row of data, then populate the Modal Box form with the desired record.  Also, the recordData I was trying to create all the informtion and populate that way, but that didnt work either.  Probably need to take that out.

Comment: Process of elimination. First rule out your object by creating a simple page that contacts that CFC object/invoke whatever, and see if you can pass in your OrgID argument and return 'stuff'. See if the 'stuff' returned matches your expectations. Once that is done, then tackle the javascript. If you are convinced there is nothing wrong with either code snips, then it has to be caching.  I have had that happen more times I care to admit. Set fire to everything caching in your browser or open firefox, or IE or something else that has never touched the page and check the results.

Comment: *the query should only send back that row of data* Well, do not just take it on faith :) As Frank describes above you need to test each piece separately and actually verify the various pieces are doing what they are "supposed to". Start at the beginning (the query) and work backward (jquery) until you pinpoint the source of the problem. Once you know "where" things break down, it is just a matter of fixing it.

Comment: I understand totally, however, since I am fairly new to jQuery, how can you tell if Jquery is doing its thing.  When I look in the DOM there doesnt seem to be an error so I cant tell if it is or not.

Comment: Does that last question mean that you have done as Frank and Leigh suggested and verified that the sql/ColdFusion stuff is doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: I have verified the Sql Query is doing what it is supposed to do by creating a page that passes an ID to the query.  This works, however the Jquery is where I seem to be going wrong I believe.  It supposed to send the ID to the Function then in the modal box display the results from that query.

Comment: *how can you tell if Jquery is doing its thing* Use a javascript debugger. Either your browser's debugger, like FF's web console, or install Firebug. Log the values sent to the CFC (ie the ID) and check the console. Then look at the http response from the CFC on the network tab. Having said that, Joel's answer explains some of the reasons why the current jquery code is not working.

Comment: In function GetOrganizationByID(), a var named "Org" is declared.  This variable is used for the query.  However, LOCAL.Org is returned.

Answer (score 0):

For a jquery ajax request you should set the **data** parameter to an object containing properties for each of the values you want to post.

```
data:  { "parameter" : "value" },
```

would be picked up by a .cfm page under the form scope (form.parameter)
and in a cfc remote method call as an argument (cfc remote arguments can also be passed in the querystring)

One issue in this code is that the OrgID argument is not passed.

try changing the line

```
var recordata = $(this).attr("href").substring(1); //trim '?' char
```

to

```
var recordata = { "OrgID" : id };
```

Another issue could be that in the cfc function returns a variable in the local scope (local.Org) , but the query name is in the variables (default) scope (name="Org")  If you are running an older version of CF

```
<cfset var local = StructNew() />
...
<cfquery datasource = "#application.dsn.name#" name="local.Org">
```

or if you are running a newer (CF 9 or later) you don't need to create the local struct

Comment: I have made the necessary changes to my code, however I am still unable to get the value of the query into the modal box.  In other words, the form should get the data passed back from the query into the Modal box.

Comment: Well, stackoverflow isn't going to write your entire page for you.  ha ha.
Right now, your query will take the content returned from the cfc and display it inside the html element with the id "content"  Is the data that ets displayed in that element the data you want?